# Reading JSON array by JSON Spirit

Tags: c++, arrays, json

I'm using this:
[JSON-Spirit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented)
In string (`json_string`) I have a lot of variables coded in JSON:

```
    namespace js = json_spirit;
    js::mValue top;
    js::read_string(std::string(json_string), top);
    json_spirit::mObject obj = top.get_obj();
    json_spirit::Array player_arr;

    csrf = obj["age"].get_str(); //

    player_arr << obj["player"].get_array();//how to get this ?
```

Array of player takes strings and int values, so I don't know how to read this.

```
{ "player":{"name":"nameplayer","key2":2,"key4":true}, "age":"15" }
```

Of course I want to take "name","key2","key4" from array called "player".

**How to do it using JSON Spirit?**

Comment: The JSON string you posted does not contain an array, is this a typo?

Comment: @carl later after `"age":"15", "res":[400000,0.66666667404895,400000,0.66666667404895,400000,0.49278917603094,"400000","18569","24960"] }` i suppose that `res` is array but i though "player" is array too

Comment: The value of "res" is an array because it is surrounded by brackets.

Comment: so it is possible to parse 'player' ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick initial potential mistake I noticed,your array should be declared like

```
{ "player":[{"name":"nameplayer"},{"key2":2},{"key4":true}], "age":"15" }
```